# Angular2 child route redirect taking precident

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have a multi-level routing in my Angular2 application and am attempting to manage the routing as cleanly as possible, but a child redirect keeps getting precidense over its parent and I haven't been able to find I fix for this.

In my app.routes.ts I have...

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: '',         redirectTo: 'matters',  pathMatch: 'full' } 
,   { path: 'login',    component: LoginComponent }
,   { path: '**',       component: NoContentComponent }
];

My Parent Route is as follows...
export const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'matters', component: MatterListComponent, canActivate: [LoginAuthGuard]
        , children:
        [  { path: '', component: MatterNotSelectedComponent, pathMatch: 'full' }
         , { path: ':id', loadChildren: () => ChildModule }
        ]
    }
];
```

And in my Child Routing I have...

```
export const routes: Routes = [
 { path: '', component: MyComponent, canActivate: [LoginAuthGuard], 
    children: 
    [
      { path: '',           redirectTo: 'summary',  pathMatch: 'full' }, 
      { path: 'summary',    component: MyComponent },
```

The routing works fine except for it always redirects to `summary` and not matters when an empty path is provided.  I have tried "prefix" on pathMatch, but nothing seems to alter this.  Have I missed something?

Comment: Can you also share your `app.module`?

Comment: Would seem to be a simple fix, added { path: '',   redirectTo: 'matters',  pathMatch: 'full' }, to the parent route :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would seem to be a simple fix, added

```
{ path: '', redirectTo: 'matters', pathMatch: 'full' },
```

to the parent route :-)